# issue working with HARDWARE acceleration / gstreamer on odroid XU4

Tags: gstreamer, hardware-acceleration, v4l2, odroid

i try to have a v4l source from my c920 logitech camera with gstreamer . I have an odroid XU4 with ubuntu 14.04 version 4.9 . I 'm trying to use the hardware acceleration to avoid using a lot of CPU .
I installed gstreamer from source since version > 1.2 is not available directly for ubuntu 14.04
I did it like this :

```
git clone -b 1.10 https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer.git
cd gstreamer
./autogen.sh
make -j 
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

I followed this tutorial :
https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=146&t=24366

I did the build from source for each dependencies needed by the tutorial in this order:
- gst-plugins-base
- gst-libav
- gst-plugins-bad

after that I get gst-plugins-good from https://github.com/mihailescu2m/gst-plugins-good and compile/install it 
But I try to make I get this error :

```
gstv4l2videodec.c:48:3: error: conflicting types for 'GstV4l2VideoCData'
 } GstV4l2VideoCData;
```

I don't understand where that come from and did not find any solution on the web. I don't want to break anything so I don't want to install wrong versions of libraries . Any idea of the source of the bug ?

Thanks for your help , i'm quite a noobie with odroid so sorry if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by applying this patch to the files concerned :  https://github.com/fnoop/gst-plugins-good/commit/3825320c95740d57501638563cdf2546dc016846
but now I get an error when I 'm trying to run

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -b -j4
```

I get :

```
dpkg-checkbuilddeps: Unmet build dependencies: libgstreamer1.0-dev (>= 1.8.0) libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev (>= 1.8.1) gstreamer1.0-plugins-base (>= 1.8.0) libsoup2.4-dev (>= 2.48) gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-doc
```

I don't know how to install the correct versions of libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev and libgstreamer1.0-dev for Ubuntu 14.04.

Does anyone know how to get to this ?

Answer (score 0):

dpkg-checkbuilddeps searches for packages installed through .deb files. This excludes installations that don't use the debian package mechanism (in your case the gstreamer package).

You can always modify the debian/build-deps file in your gst-plugins-good repo by removing the `(>= 1.8.0)` for instance for all unmet dependencies. Then you can try to see if the build succeeds anyway. But then you have to make sure you installed all missing deps by hand with there correct version.